# Problems with BinaryFormatter on class with DataContract?

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I have a class

```
[DataContract]
    public class Car
   {
        public bool pbIsHatchBack;
        string prSt = "royi";

    }
```

And i want to serialize it with **BinaryFormatter**:

```
  BinaryFormatter binFormat = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream fStream = new FileStream("c:\\CarData.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        binFormat.Serialize(fStream, carObj);
        fStream.Close();
```

But u get this error

> Type 'SerializationTypes+Car' in Assembly 'ConsoleApplication2,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked
>   as serializable.

If i remove the [**DataContract**] and replace it with [**Serializable**] its **ok**. but **why** ?

how WCF does it behind the scene (when tcpBinding ?)?

Why **can't** i use the DataContract ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WCF does not use the `BinaryFormatter` to serialize its objects, it uses either the `DataContractSerializer` (by default) or some of its other serializers (`XmlSerializer`, `DataContractJsonSerializer`, etc). `BinaryFormatter` was released before WCF (in .NET Framework 1.0, IIRC) so is not aware of the `[DataContract]`/`[DataMember]` attributes (which were released in .NET Framework 3.0, along with WCF.

On `netTcpBinding` WCF still uses the `DataContractSerializer`, but instead of using a "normal" XML reader/writer, it uses a binary-aware XML reader/writer, which is how we have the binary encoding in WCF.

The WCF serializers understand the `[Serializable]` attribute, so you can use it with WCF as well. Or you can also use both attributes, if you want your type to be serializable by the `BinaryFormatter` but use the more fine-grained control that the [DC]/[DM] attributes give you.

Comment: great man thanks. i searching the web for serialize and (!!) desirelize exmplae for dataContractSerializer with binary... could find some... do you have any link :) ?